# How initialise Zend1 with composer with php8?

Tags: php, zend-framework

I want to use zend1 with composer and initialize the project.

My php version is

```
$ php -v
PHP 8.1.9 (cli) (built: Aug  5 2022 11:22:59) (NTS)
Copyright (c) The PHP Group
Zend Engine v4.1.9, Copyright (c) Zend Technologies
```

I have the `composer.json` with

```
{
    "require": {
        "zendframework/zendframework1": "^1.12"
    }
}
```

when I execute the initilazation I get

```
$ ./vendor/zendframework/zendframework1/bin/zf.sh create project app
PHP Fatal error:  Array and string offset access syntax with curly braces is no longer supported in ./vendor/zendframework/zendframework1/library/Zend/Tool/Project/Context/Zf/ApplicationConfigFile.php on line 142

Fatal error: Array and string offset access syntax with curly braces is no longer supported in ./vendor/zendframework/zendframework1/library/Zend/Tool/Project/Context/Zf/ApplicationConfigFile.php on line 142
```

I assume there is a change in the php version. I prefer not to touch the `ApplicationConfigFile.php` in the package. how can this be resolved?

Answer (score 3):

The old ZF1 project is not going to work well on PHP8, there are lots of updates required. Luckily there is an [open source initiative](https://github.com/Shardj/zf1-future) to keep ZF1 alive and up-to date. You can change `"zendframework/zendframework1": "^1.12"` to `"shardj/zf1-future": "^1.21"` in your composer config and go about your business.